# Upgrading Windows XP to Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-xp

I would like to upgrade from Windows XP to Windows 10 but don't know the way.

Any help would be amazing.

Comment: There is no upgrade path, windows 10 must be installed clean, so back up important files before installing W10.

Comment: @Moab - that's the answer, not merely a comment. You should post it as such.

Comment: Technically, you could upgrade XP to Vista, then Vista to 10.  It's a bad idea though and you will probably get stuck with 32 bit.  Nothing is better than a fresh install.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas - There is no direct upgrade path from Vista to Windows 10.  **So one would have to upgrade Windows XP to Windows 7.**

Comment: @Ramhound, I didn't see the part in [this article](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-upgrade-windows-vista-windows-10) that said that you need windows 7 in the middle.  DOUGH!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I need to upgrade from Windows XP to Windows 10 but don't know the way.

There is no direct upgrade path from Windows XP to Windows 10.  If you attempted to upgrade to Windows 10, by running the setup executable on a Windows 10 installation media, the end result would be a clean install of Windows 10.

The only path is an indirect upgrade path from Windows 7 to Windows 10, by first upgrading Windows XP to Windows 7, you can use a [KMS Windows 7 license key](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/kmsclientkeys) for the proper edition of Windows 7 to acomplish this.  Of course the resulting Windows 10 installation, would require a license of it's own, otherwise it won't be able to activate.

All legal valid Windows 10 installations require a license, there is **absolutely no way** to run Windows 10 for free legally, the cost of the Windows 10 license due to the free upgrade offer **was built into the previous costs of the valid Windows license you upgrade from.**

Comment: I have upgraded Windows 8 to Windows 8.1 using a KMS license key, so I know the upgrade from Windows XP to Windows 7 can be acomplished using the same approach, but whatever the final version of Windows will be requires a license.  **You cannot activate Windows 7 or Windows 10 with a KMS license.**